# Write in output file in python

Tags: python, list, file

I have a list like as follows

```
list1 = [['abc',{2:1,3:4,5:6}],['xyz',{4:0,9:5,7:8}],.......]]
```

I want write the list in a o/p file in the following format:

```
'abc' 2:1 3:4 5:6
'xyz' 4:0 9:5 7:8
```

I tried different ways, but not able to get it in the above format.Let me also mention that `len(list1) = 30000`.Please suggest me an optimized way

Comment: so you want the output to have only one long line? by the way, please post your code you are using so that we can help you instead of us writing code for you.

Answer (score 2):

```
list1 = [['abc', {2: 1, 3: 4, 5: 6}], ['xyz', {4: 0, 9: 5, 7: 8}]]

with open('some.txt', 'w') as output_file:
    for k, v in list1:
        output_file.write('\'{}\' {}\n'.format(
            k, ' '.join('{}:{}'.format(key, val) for key, val in v.items())))
```

For Python 3 just use `v.items()`.